# Using structures for multiple same arrays-in finding average value in float

Tags: c, arrays, structure, average

Would like to seek help! 
I have marks for 3 subjects (Maths, English & Science) to enter into three different arrays.

I use "structure" based on the suggestions.

I could not print the average value for each subjects and total subject. Average values are showing zero.

```
for (int i = 0; i < num && i < Max_NUM; i++)
{
  for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) 
        { //loop calculating sum of array elements
                        sum=(sum+std[i].subject[j]); //sum of mark for 3 subjects 
                        sum2=sum/num;  
                    std[i].subject[j] =(sum2/Max_Grade)*100; // average mark

                //for total average mark (sub 0 avg mark+ sub 1 avg mark+ sub 2 avg mark)
                totalSUB =(std[i].subject[0]+std[i].subject[1]+std[i].subject[2])/3;
         }
                   //to print 3lines: for average marks of each subject: sub 0, sub 1, sub2  
                  printf("\nAverage mark: %.2f",std[i].subject[j]);  

                  //to print average marks for each subject: sub 0, sub 1, sub2  
                  printf("\nTotalSUB- Average mark: %.2f",totalSUB);  
                   return 0; 
                   }  //end of if
```

error in output as in picture attached: [image]
full code as below:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
        #include <stdlib.h>
        #define Max_Grade 415
        #define Max_NUM 150
                int main()
                {
                    int i,j,num;//variable declaration
                    double avg=0.0,sum=0.0, sum2=0.0, totalSUB=0.0;
                    struct student 
                    {
                         double subject[3];
                    };
                    struct student std[Max_NUM];
                    printf("Enter number of students: ");
                    scanf("%d",&num);
// for loop to read i'th student's j'th subject
for (int i = 0; i < num && i < Max_NUM; i++)
{
  for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) 
  {
     printf("Enter marks of student %d for subject %d: ", i, j);
     scanf("%f", &std[i].subject[j]);
     //sleep(2);
  }
}
for (int i = 0; i < num && i < Max_NUM; i++)
{
  for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) 
        { //loop calculating sum of array elements
                        sum=(sum+std[i].subject[j]); //sum of mark for 3 subjects 
                        sum2=sum/num;  
                    std[i].subject[j] =(sum2/Max_Grade)*100; // average mark

                //for total average mark (sub 0 avg mark+ sub 1 avg mark+ sub 2 avg mark)
                totalSUB =(std[i].subject[0]+std[i].subject[1]+std[i].subject[2])/3;
         }
                   //to print 3lines: for average marks of each subject: sub 0, sub 1, sub2  
                  printf("\nAverage mark: %.2f",std[i].subject[j]);  

                  //to print average marks for each subject: sub 0, sub 1, sub2  
                  printf("\nTotalSUB- Average mark: %.2f",totalSUB);  
                   return 0; 
                   }  //end of if

               } //end of int main()
```

Comment: Use functions or structures.

Answer (score 0):

You achieve the same as shown below. Make a structure with subjects you want, and allocate the memory for that many students. In a loop for each student `std` you can read subject marks for each. The same way you can compute the average scores as well.

```
struct student {
  int subject[3];
};

struct student std[Max_NUM];

printf("Enter number of students: ");
scanf("%d",&num);

/* for loop to read i'th student's j'th subject*/
for (int i = 0; i < num && i < Max_NUM; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
     printf("Enter marks of student %d for subject %d: ", i, j);
     scanf("%d", &std[i].subject[j]);
  }
}
```

Comment: hi Sunil, thanks for reply. entering marks will be float, thus i amend `double j;` and `double subject[3];` in the struct student 
change in the printf line to this `printf("Enter marks of student %d \n for subject %f: ", i, j);`  but got error in scanf line -error message: array subscript is not an integer -at `scanf("%d", &std[i].subject[j]);`

Comment: @SKmay, `j` is one of 3 subjects not marks variable. What you need is a `double` type in struct student declaration instead of `int` and while reading change `%d` in `scanf` to `%f` specifier.

Comment: thanks sunil, for finding average scores. I have difficulties in printing average value for each student. I have amend in my main post. Appreciate on your help